# Rigidbody.objects_add.poll() failed!

Tags: python, rigid-body-simulation

After the script that was working as mentioned in [my earlier post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32878/blender-background-simulation-gui-less-is-different-from-the-actual-simulation). I am trying to create a blend file that has the scene setup and a script that has the locations of the objects available in the blend scene. I am able to see the new positions created by the script to the objects in the blend scene. But I am not able to bake them all. I get the below error.

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

This is relevant to the lines

```
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
```

Let me know if you have come across this kind of error. How do I make the context correct. When I try to the print the objects that are in the scene, I am able to see the objects in the blend file. What does the context here mean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My rigidbody objects where already added in the scene. So I actually donot need to objects_add method at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should deselect non mesh objects before adding rigid body objects

```
 bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #clear selection
 candidate_list = [item.name for item in bpy.data.objects if item.type == "MESH"]
for object_name in candidate_list:
    bpy.data.objects[object_name].select = True
```

this also should be done when clearing the scene if you want to keep the camera and light sources. and regarding the context see this answer [poll() failed, context incorrect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/5113)